# how do you use useParams correctly to display data

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to display information grabbing the id and getting to display their information. However, it seems that I'm sending the id but it isn't redirecting me to the page-details.

```
import React from 'react';
import {Container, Row, Col } from 'react-bootstrap'
import './App.css';
import Top from './top.js';
import Bottom from './bottom';
import Right from './right';
import Left from './left';
import Center from './center';
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap';
import { BrowserRouter  as Router , Route, Switch} from "react-router-dom";
import ProductsDetail from './product-detail';

function App(props) {
  return (
    <Router>
          <Container fluid className="p-0 min-vh-100 d-flex flex-column">
              <Row fluid className = "flex-grow-0 flex-shrink-0 shadow-sm" > 
                <bs.Col className = "px-3 py-2">
                  <Top/>

                </bs.Col>
              </Row>

              <Row noGutters className = "flex-grow-1">
                <Col md="2" className ="px-3 py-4 shadow" style ={{backgroundColor: "#99CCCC"}}>
                  <Left/>
                </Col>

                <Col md="8">
                  <Switch>
                    <Route path ="/">
                      <Center />
                    </Route>
                    <Route path = "/product-detail/:productid">
                        <ProductsDetail />
                    </Route>
                  </Switch>
                </Col>

                <Col md = "2" className = "px-3 py-4 shadow" style ={{backgroundColor: "#343a40"}}>
                  <Right/>
                </Col>
              </Row>

              <Row fluid>
                <Col className = "d-flex justify-content-center px-3 py-2" style ={{backgroundColor: "#28a745"}}><Bottom/></Col>
              </Row> 
          </Container>
      </Router>
  )

}

export default App;
```

This is the product-detail page

```
import React from 'react';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

function ProductsDetail(props) {

    const {productid} = useParams()
            return (
                <div>
                    <p>
                        Description: {productid}
                    </p>
                </div>
            )

}

export default ProductsDetail;
```

and this is the product-cards where I'm using the link to send the id

```
import React from 'react';
import * as bs from 'react-bootstrap';
import {Link} from "react-router-dom";
import {
    Card, Button,Container, Row, Col 
  } from 'react-bootstrap';



function ProductCard(props) {
  return (
        <Card style={{ width: '10rem' }}>
            <Link to = {`/product-detail/${props.product.id}`} className='btn btn-primary' style={{position:'absolute', marginTop:-5, alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}> 

                Details

                </Link>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src={`/media/products/${props.product.filename}-1.png`} />
        <Card.Body>

        <Card.Title>{props.product.name}</Card.Title>
        <Card.Text>
        Price: ${props.product.price}
        </Card.Text>
        </Card.Body>
        </Card>

  )

}

export default ProductCard;
```

I'm trying to use useParams to grab the id on the product-detail.js but it isn't redirecting me to that page.
I

Comment: what do you mean by `useParams` does not redirect? it should not redirect you to any page

Answer (score 0):

I think that your problem is on the product-cards component. the part that you use `<link>` tag.

your `<Link>` tag should be like this:

```
        <Link to = {`/product-detail/${props.productid.id}`} > 
               Details
        </Link>
```

you write : `${props.product.id}` but it should be like :`{props.productid.id}`